# Normal Activity and Tab Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-tabactivity

I am developing an app. Its first page is a login screen. When successfully logged in I want to take the user to a tabbed activity. How can I do this in android?
Thanks

Comment: Call [startActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) once the login is successful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android, starting an `Activity` is done with an `Intent` object, like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,YourActivity.class);
this.startActivity(intent);
```